# Develop application for Samsung fridge

Tags: operating-system, programming-languages

I'm investigating what it takes to develop your own application for a Samsung Fridge. I've been searching the web, but I can't seem to find any useful links of anyone programming or developing their own apps for a Samsung Fridge.

I want to know if it's even possible to develop your own application and deploy it or do you have to work inside or collaborate with Samsung to achieve this?

Furthermore, does anyone know that OS the Samsung Fridges running on and what language are the existing applications written in?

I want to investigate all this because I'm clearly interested in making such an application and also, I'm just curious how far they've gotten in this field or if it's just drop dead or not mature enough for open development yet.

**Edit:** http://www.samsung.com/us/topic/apps-on-your-fridge

Comment: You may be able to overclock if you move the controller to the freezer compartment.

Comment: For debugging you'll probably want an **In Circuit Emulator** (ICE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be a bit more specific about which fridge you're talking about? I looked at a couple of models, but computer control didn't show up on the features lists.

OH! It's the RF4289, but it isn't available internationally (yet?). The user's manual says that the software is opensourse, distributed under GPL and can be obtained by sending samsung a request at css.request@samsung.com

Does this belong at cooking.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the Samsung "smart" fridge with WiFi etc: http://www.engadget.com/2011/04/18/samsungs-rf4289-wifi-smart-fridge-gets-a-dumb-3-499-price/

Comment: I've added a link in the original post.

Comment: I'm not really talking about one specific fridge I suppose all of the Samsung Fridges uses the same OS and the same applications.

Comment: Well, not quite all. As **most** of them don't have a touch screens. I didn't find _anything_ with wifi and fridge on the /au or /uk sites. Only the US site seems to have a series of fridges with wifi. The engadget article does suggest that it's a new concept.